# python loop returning wrong answer

Tags: python

I want my loop to return true if any element of positions match with the string. First, i split to find the position needed. `positions = ['founder','cto','partner']` and string is `person_title = "director and cto at company"`

My code:

```
def check_title(person_title,positions):

     person_titles = person_title.split(" ")
     for one_title in person_titles:
        for one_position_check in positions:
            if  one_position_check == one_title :
                answer = True
            
            else:
               answer = False
  return answer
```

The answer should be True but I am getting False. Any help?

Comment: Then you need to `return True` as soon as you find a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `answer` to `True`, you should simply `return True`. Or else, after finding a match, a non-match might change `answer` to `False` again.

Do something like this.

```
def check_title(person_title,positions):

     person_titles = person_title.split(" ")
     for one_title in person_titles:
        for one_position_check in positions:
            if  one_position_check == one_title :
                return True

     return False
```

Comment: `split` splits by the space by default

Comment: @funnydman OP added it. Maybe he wants it for clarity. I don't think it's my job to change it, so I will leave it in the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could return True when match instead of looking through all and assign it to answer. But the simpler and faster would be using sets and checking for any intersection.

### A better solution avoiding nests

```py
positions = ['founder','cto','partner'] 
person_title = "director and cto at company"

def check_title(person_title: str, positions: list) -> bool:
     positions_ = set(positions)
     person_titles = {title for title in person_title.split()}
    
     return any(person_titles.intersection(positions_))
```